# Where should settings files be stored?

Tags: python, wxpython, application-settings

I'm writing an application in python (using wxPython for the gui) and I'm looking for a platform independent way to decide where to store application settings files.  On linux systems, where is it customary to store application settings files?  How about on Mac, and Windows (all modern versions)?

Ideally I'd like to have a module that provides a platform agnostic interface to locate these files.  Does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wxPython has your back. You want wx.StandardPaths. There's a good example included with the wxPython demo.

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard for this by freedesktop.org that you may find useful:
http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: This is useful for linux and perhaps mac as well.  What about for windows?  And is there a standard module that can abstract this so I don't have to code all these details?

Comment: @David: For windows you could use XDG_CONFIG_HOME,XDG_DATA_HOME with different default values (e.g. "%HOME%\Application Data"). The other variables are not really sensible for windows as windows applications usually have all their data and config files in their installation directory. I don't know of a python module, but it shouldn't be that hard or much work to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

On linux, there's really not a standard way. A lot of programs, especially newer python programs I've seen, use `~/.config/appname/`. Of course the older ones like bash, vi, etc just add a hidden file in `~/`. It depends, what kind of settings are these?

Those are obviously user run programs. System programs generally store their config files somewhere in `/etc/`

*Edit:*

`~/.config/appname/` seems to be more standard than I thought.

```
~ $ ll config
total 84K

drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-12-17 09:48 akonadi/
drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-12-04 15:48 autokey/
drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-11-06 01:45 autostart/
drwx------ 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-11-23 22:32 enchant/
drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-11-25 21:13 FreeCAD/
drwx------ 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-12-21 09:16 gtk-2.0/
drwx------ 3 falmarri 4.0K 2010-12-11 13:43 ibus/
drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-11-06 02:20 kde.org/
drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-11-06 02:46 qtcurve/
drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-11-17 13:49 Trolltech/
drwxr-xr-x 2 falmarri 4.0K 2010-11-17 23:29 vlc/
-rw-r--r-- 1 falmarri  31K 2010-12-21 20:51 Trolltech.conf
-rw------- 1 falmarri  632 2010-11-06 01:40 user-dirs.dirs
-rw-r--r-- 1 falmarri    5 2010-11-06 01:40 user-dirs.locale
```

Comment: I've seen several apps on both Unix systems and Windows (even the same apps, ported to different platforms) use the hidden file (like ~/.hgrc).  It seems to work pretty well, and it's a consistent place to look.

Comment: Well using a hidden file is pretty much given. It just depends where. `~/.file` is pretty standard. The problem is that with so many programs now, the home directory is being filled up with `.xrc` files. I kind of like the `~/.config/appname/` location.